# The import javax.servelt cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Getting the error here that says `The import javax.servelt cannot be resolved`

[image]

I set the targeted runtime for my project here.

[image]

Pulling my hair out over here! I've stack overflowed this error for a while now and everyone keeps saying you need to set the target runtime but for some reason it is not fixing the problem for me.

Comment: It's `javax.servlet` and not `javax.servelt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this:

> The import javax.servelt cannot be resolved

doesn't exist

you want this `javax.servlet`

Notice the spelling of serv**let**  not serv**elt**

Comment: that's embarrassing. thank you!

Comment: @gmustudent happens to the best of us in text editors.

Answer (score 0):

its actually import javax.servlet